# Filling out missing values in columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset named as **com**, and I want to fill the **missing values** using the appropriate filters in the dataset..

I have replaced the question mark by Nan, by using this line of code:

```
com.replace('?', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

Now I want to fill the missing values..

I have tried this code but its not working and return the same dataset containing NaN values

```
com.fillna(com.mean(), inplace=True)
```

csv file

https://1drv.ms/f/s!Au0AN4RPO4G4g3iFTbFTiEsakKIE

view of the csv

[csv image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnHuH.png)

Output as show by the system:

[image]

Comment: okay i am uploading it

Comment: i have uploaded a csv file

Comment: i didn't ask you to upload your whole dataset, we need just some rows. just run df.head() and share the results

Comment: have a look on it